# How to enable remote connection in Mysql 8.0 on Debian 10

Tags: mysql, connection

I'm trying to connect remotely to mysql and this isn't possible, I'm running Debian 10 and mysql server 8.0 in my server, I did try to do the changes in  `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to change or comment bind-address and skip-networking but It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, in Mysql 8.0 remote connections It doesn't need enable in remote connection you only need to create a new user and give it grant privileges, the command in sql console that I used :

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH privileges;
```

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_UkiAMyPpk